# Was Mace Windu apologetic to Ahsoka Tano?

Tags: star-wars, the-clone-wars, ahsoka-tano

Was Mace Windu apologetic to Ahsoka Tano? When she is invited to rejoin the Jedi Order, he says to her; "this was actually your great trial, now we see that. We understand that the Force works in mysterious ways, and because of this trial, you have become a greater Jedi than you would have otherwise". Doesn't sound like an apology does it? So was it a praise, an observation, or a subtle attempt to deflect blame of his mistake onto the Force?

Answer (score 15):

No, he is not being apologetic. Lets take a look at his quote in context.

> **Ki-Adi-Mundi:** This is the true sign of a Jedi Knight.
>   **Mace Windu:** This was actually your great trial. Now we see that. We understand that the Force works in mysterious ways, and because of this trial, you have become a greater Jedi than you would have otherwise.
>   **Yoda:** Back into the Order you may come.
>   <sub>[Star Wars: The Clone Wars - The Wrong Jedi](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/The_Wrong_Jedi)</sub>

The subtext is that they were wrong to kick her out of the Order, and they make this right by letting her back in. However, the Council considered her ordeal in hindsight as being her Trials and, having proven herself ready and worthy, offered her the promotion to Jedi Knight. They are not apologizing, or offering the position out of some sense of guilt, or even blaming the Force. They are simply acknowledging something happened, and that as a result, Ahsoka is a worthy of being a Jedi Knight.

Comment: I feel like if someone is correcting their mistake they're inherently apologising?

Comment: Eh... I don't agree. Making right is not the same as feeling regret. Both together is apologetic, but I don't think half is. OP is asking if Windu was apologetic. Given his personality and the context of the situation, I don't believe he was.

Comment: I feel like his personality would contribute in disguising his apology as something that wouldn't normally be apologetic. But that's outside my expertise, I can't analyse behaviours and tell you what they mean. I personally don't have an opinion on how apologetic he was :) Just trying to offer opinions which may suggest confusion to help improve your answer

Answer (score 7):

Going by his wording, and given what we understand about the Star Wars universe, Mace's words may not have been an attempt to deflect blame, but rather an accurate assessment of the situation.

The Force does have a will of it's own, and it does work in mysterious ways.  For example, we can say that Anakin was indeed the one that brought balance to the Force, despite the fact that he spent so many years working for Palpatine.  The Force does not directly arrange events to quickly come to the conclusion that it's will demands, but rather guides people through experiences (some good and some bad).  In short, there appears to be an allegory being drawn between the Force and the Judaeo-Christian God (the most blatant example of this being "the Force works in mysterious ways").  The biggest difference between these two concepts is that, in the Star Wars universe, the existence of the Force is not as fiercely debated.

With that in mind, consider the fact that both Mace and Ahsoka have dedicated their lives to the service of the will of the Force.  They understand that the events in their lives are guided by the Force, and that sometimes even their actions are guided by the Force (consider Luke's blindfold lightsaber training).  So when Mace says that this was Ahsoka's great trial, he may not be attempting to deflect blame.  He may very well be sincerely congratulating Ahsoka for passing the trial that the Force had given her.

Comment: Ahsoka didn't seem impressed by his statement to her; as he says it, she crosses her arms and frowns slightly, so she's clearly not buying it, she's not impressed.

Answer (score 1):

He was not being apologetic. Nor was he shifting blame; there is not enough context to conclude that. He could have been more forthcoming with information, and could have been significantly more tactful; for example, he could have said, "We listened to the force beforehand, and it said to remove you," before saying the line about "This was your great trial." That would have been more acceptable, I'm sure.

But that was not her story. She rejected the Jedi Order for reasons, and she never actually says what they were. She tells Ezra, "I left the Order." She never says why, to my knowledge. We surmise that she quit because the Order had proved itself untrustworthy, but there might be other reasons yet unknown.

As for the last question -- Certainly it was an observation; it may have been praise of a sort.

Answer (score 0):

I don’t think he was apologetic. I mean, the force does work in mysterious ways, but the Jedi are supposed to be understanding and honest. It was their own fault she was put through that, and therefore their fault that she left.

Comment: Hi, welcome to SF&F.  This doesn't fully answer the question; see the last line "was it praise, an observation, or a subtle attempt to deflect blame?"  If it wasn't apologetic, what was it?